# Whether there is always an intersection between Column Space and Nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose there is a matrix $A$ that satisfies $Ax=b$, and it have two solutions $c$ and $d$.
Then we can know $Ac=b$ and $Ad=b$, so $A(c-d)=0$. But $c$ and $d$ are the two column vectors of matrix $A$, and $c-d$ is a linear combination of column vectors, so $c-d$ should be in the Column Space. But $c-d$ also satisfies $Ax=0$, so it should also be in Nullspace. How should I understand this problem from the perspective of Column Space and Nullspace?

Comment: Have you covered the concept of a "subspace" of a vector space yet?

Comment: $c-d$ isn't a combination of columns of $A$.  Rather, $A(c-d)$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$.  It's quite common for $(c-d)$ and $A(c-d)$ to be vectors of different dimensions.  In your example, $c-d$ is a vector in the null space of $A$, and $A(c-d)$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ that happens to be the 0 vector.

Comment: You have to study the basic concepts of linear algebra again. Nullspace and colum space have intersection $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector may or may not lie in the nullspace of a given matrix. Multiplying a matrix with a vector yields a linear combination of the columns of the matrix, so the *result* of the multiplication lies in the column space.

$c-d$ is a vector in the nullspace of $A$. $c$ and $d$ may or may not be in the nullspace, depending on whether $b = 0$. The vectors $Ac, Ad$ and $A(c-d)$ are all linear combinations of the columns of $A$ and lie in the column space of $A$. in this case, the entries of $c-d, c$ and $d$ are the *coefficients* of these linear combination.

If $A$ is $m\times n$ with $m\neq n$, then the nullspace and the column space do not have anything to do with one another (the nullspace consists of $n\times 1$ vectors, while the column space consists of $m\times 1$ vectors). It would be nonsensical to ask about their intersection.

If $A$ is square, then it makes sense to ask about the intersection of the two spaces. The zero vector will definitely be there. Maybe other vectors will too. For instance, for the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
both the column space and the nullspace are spanned by $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, and the two spaces are equal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It has some inspiration for me. Please allow me to confirm the conclusion : whether c-d is in the Nullspace of A, and vector A(c-d) is in the Column Space of A? If this is true, then my mistake is that i think c-d is both in Column Space and in Nullspace and ignored matrix A.

Comment: @JachinNg Yes, $c-d$ is in the nullspace, while $A(c-d)$ is in the column space.